# How to make MySQL return conflicting key on duplicate key? See inside

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

Say, I've got a simple table: `id` as primary key, and `field`. Then i do:
`INSERT INTO table(id,field) VALUES (1,'blah')`
and then I do it again. So, how can I make MySQL return following:

> id
>
> 1

So that it works like SELECT-ing conflicted key?

Comment: Well, it just won't make you "do it again", so there will never be conflicting keys, as long as you've defined "id" as a primary key. Why do you need this?

Comment: MySQL will return a duplicate-key error - how to analyze it is up to your language and API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible without some code, mysql will return a generic duplicate key error

With-Code solution:

Are you using an  AUTO_INCREMENT column ?

If you use INSERT IGNORE and the row is ignored,

the AUTO_INCREMENT counter is not incremented and LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0,

which reflects that no row was inserted.

so:

- INSERT IGNORE
- if LAST_INSERT_ID(), then done (new row was inserted)
- else your data is duplicate

[last_insert_id() documentation >](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

[insert Ignore documentation >](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the following...

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

    CREATE TABLE my_table(my_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,my_field VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,conflict TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);

    INSERT INTO my_table (my_id,my_field) VALUES (1,'blah') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE conflict = 1;

    SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE conflict = 1;
    Empty set (0.00 sec)

    INSERT INTO my_table (my_id,my_field) VALUES (1,'blah') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE conflict = 1;
    Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.07 sec)

    SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE conflict = 1;
    +-------+----------+----------+
    | my_id | my_field | conflict |
    +-------+----------+----------+
    |     1 | blah     |        1 |
    +-------+----------+----------+
```